# Show media:thumbnail in aggregator item

Tags: views, 8, entities, feeds

I am using drupal core aggregator to show images from instagram on my website. i get the rss using https://web.stagram.com/rss/n/page_name. The images are dispalyed as media:thumbnail in the rss, and they are rendered correctly in aggregator/sources in the aggregator/source/1 path. But only the title and link are displayed in the aggregator block.